# Symfony2 two installations in two folders share users unwantingly

Tags: php, symfony

I've got the following setup:

www.domain.com/application1 {seperate symfony installation & DB}
www.domain.com/application2 {seperate symfony installation & DB}

Both application have different users, however if a user with user_id 1 logs into application1 and then changes the URL to www.domain.com/application2 he is allowed in if there exists a valid user with the same ID in application2.

I'm breaking my head about this and can't get a decent working solution, as they share the same host, it seems using the Host limitation in the security.yml is out of the question.

**Security.yml snippet**

```
firewalls:
    secured_area:
         pattern:   ^/
         anonymous: ~
         form_login:
             csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
             login_path: login
             check_path: login_check
         logout:
             path:   /logout
             target: /
```

Any pointers into the right direction are greatly appreciated.

**Edit 1**
Both secrets are different, the usernames and passwords are also different. When trying to login in application2 with a user from application1 it fails as it should do. But once logged in they can see both applications.

Comment: Do they both have the same secret: in app/config/parameters.yml

Comment: No they're both different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the above comment I ended up solving it as follows:

Code suggested for refreshUser on the Symfony site
[Symfony Docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html)

```
public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
{
    $class = get_class($user);
    if (!$this->supportsClass($class)) {
        throw new UnsupportedUserException(
            sprintf(
                'Instances of "%s" are not supported.',
                $class
            )
        );
    }

    return $this->find($user->getId());
}
```

My adaption to check for more then just the ID

```
public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
{
    $class = get_class($user);
    $refreshedUser = $this->find($user->getPersoonId());
    if (!$this->supportsClass($class)) {
        throw new UnsupportedUserException(
            sprintf(
                'Instances of "%s" are not supported.',
                $class
            )
        );
    }
    if($refreshedUser->getUsername()!=$user->getUsername()&&$refreshedUser->getPassword()!=$user->getPassword()){
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException('Unable to find user');
    }

    return $refreshedUser;
}
```

I would appreciate comments on my solution, and if this situation is wanted.

Thanks for the time and effort of everyone.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've written any PHP (let alone symfony), but...

I noticed when I checked [the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html) that `always_authenticate_before_granting` defaults to `false`.  You might want to change that to `true` in the security section of both apps's security.yml.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i've tried it and I don't see any difference. My next step will be a rewrite of the refrshUser function. Not sure yet to what and I hope it's the right thing to do.